# Styled Components w/o defaultProps w/ typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am updating a library of React Styled Components to:

1. Apply TypeScript (v4.1)
2. Eliminate the use of defaultProps (since it is apparently on the React depreciation list)

I am seeking general advise on my new pattern with regard to Typescript and I know there may be better ways to handle the default props. Just looking for a meaningful discussion of different alternatives. Thanks!

```js
// theme comes from styled-componets theme prover and is typed

// Typing

type Clr = 'red' | 'blue' | 'green'
type Int = 'L' | 'D'

type TBox = {
  clr: Clr,
  int: Int,
}

interface IBox {
  clr: Clr,
  int: Int,
  children: JsxElement[]
}

// OLD Pattern - using defaultProps

export const Box = styled.div<IBox>`
  background-color : ${({theme, clr, int})=>theme.fnt.clr[clr][int]};
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
`

Box.defaultProps = {
  clr: 'green',
  int: 'D'
}

// NEW Pattern - without defaultProps - using a wrapper 

export const Box2A: (props: Readonly<Partial<IBox>>) => JSX.Element = (props) => {
  return <Box2Style {...Box2DefaultProps} {...props} />;
};

const Box2Style = styled.div<TBox>`
  background-color : ${({theme, clr, int})=>theme.fnt.clr[clr][int]};
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
`
const Box2DefaultProps: TBox = {
  clr: 'green',
  int: 'D'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Attaching additional props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props)

> To avoid unnecessary wrappers that just pass on some props to the
> rendered component, or element, you can use the [`.attrs` constructor](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs). It
> allows you to attach additional props (or "attributes") to a
> component.

```
export const Box = styled.div<TBox>` // can use IBox interface or TBox type
  background-color : ${({ theme, clr, int }) => theme.fnt.clr[clr][int]};
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
`

Box.defaultProps = {
  clr: 'green',
  int: 'D'
}
```

Becomes

```
export const Box = styled.div.attrs<TBox>(({ clr, int }) => ({
  clr: clr || 'green',
  int: int || 'D',
}))<TBox>` // can use IBox interface or TBox type
  background-color : ${({ theme, clr, int }) => theme.fnt.clr[clr][int]};
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
`
```

or

```
export const Box = styled.div.attrs<TBox>(({ clr = "green", int = "D" }) => ({
  clr,
  int,
}))<TBox>` // can use IBox interface or TBox type
  background-color : ${({ theme, clr, int }) => theme.fnt.clr[clr][int]};
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
`
```

I'm not a typescript expert by any means, so the interfaces may need to be tweaked, and there's a closed github [issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1959#issuecomment-497761798) I found regarding typescript and `.attrs` syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen something about using .attrs but was concerned that it would not make default props but would override any props coming in. I will play with your suggestion.

Comment: @AndyB I had considered that as well, but confirmed it works in my own code.

Answer (score 0):

@DrewReese You are correct. The typescript is making me a little nuts but this seems to be functional. I was also able to setup to add in additional props (something I had not dealt with yet. Typing the new props does not make sense to me but I feel like I am on the write path.

```js
export const BoxT = styled.div.attrs<TBox>(
  ({clr= 'blue', int= 'L'}) => {
    const id = 'TBox test';
    const onClick = () => console.log('clicked')
    return { onClick, id, clr, int }
  }
)<TBox>`
  background-color : ${({theme, clr, int})=>theme.fnt.clr[clr][int]};
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
`
```